# run mootools function on each element except the one

Tags: function, events, mootools

I have two maps:

```
var map1 = document.id('map1');
var map2 = document.id('map2');
```

The second map is hidden.

```
map2.setStyle('display','none');
```

On the first map there is an element (link) that has an unique id - I would like to run another function when this element is clicked (hide the first map and show the second one).

I have:

```
  var links = document.id('map1').getElements('a');     

  links.each(function(link) { 
  link.addEvent('click', function(e) {
   e.stop();
    //do something with links
  });
```

I try in such a way:

```
var unique_link = document.id('my_unique_id').getElements('a');

unique_link.addEvent("click", function(){
links.removeEvent('click');
map1.setStyle('display','none');
map2.setStyle('display','block');
var links = document.id('map2').getElements('a'); 
});
```

but when I click this unique element, the first function is still running.

Answer (score 1):

`Element.removeEvent` does not work this way. It requires that you pass ***both*** the name of the event (click) and the function that is handling it. This is because there may be multiple functions which are called when `click` is fired. You can use `Element.removeEvents` to remove all click-handling functions but this might not be what you really want (although it's probably fine). To do it best you'd do this:

```
var handler = function(e) { e.stop(); /* do something with links */ }),
    links = document.id('map1').getElements('a');

links.addEvent('click', handler);

document.id('my_unique_id').getElements('a').addEvent('click', function() {
    links.removeEvent('click', handler);
    /* Other stuff */
});
```

Oh and, by the way, this:

```
document.id('some_id').getElements('.some-selector');
```

can be written like this:

```
$$('#some_id .some-selector');
```

Comment: Thanks. What about links event delegation? I mean: var links = document.id, links.each(function(link) {
  link.addEvent('click',function() {
    //assign actions here
  }); Every link has an unique value that I use to display data. How should I get this value using your way?

Comment: Now I get all value: value1, value2, value3 etc.

Comment: Well, I'd need more information about these values and where you're getting them but basically `$$('#map1 a')` is a collection of links and if you do `$$('#map1 a').addEvent('click', someFunction);` it will assign `someFunction` as the click handler for each of them (there is no delegation happening). Inside `someFunction`, `this` will be the `a` tag that was clicked. So that might be useful to you. The function will also be passed an event object which may be handy.

Comment: If you want to do delegation, MT does support this. You would do it like this: `document.id('map1').addEvent('click:relay(a)', someFunction);` Now, in this case, I believe that inside of `someFunction`, `this` will be your `#map1` element rather than your `a` tag. However, `someFunction` gets two arguments, first is an event objected and the second is the clicked element (your `a` tag). So this may be a better way to handle this stuff. There are many good reasons to use delegation.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of your problem is that you're trying to toggle between maps and when you toggle, click event handlers are attached to the maps links.

First for toggling, you'll want to keep track of which one is visible so that you can properly hide it and make the other visible:

```
var unique_link = $$('#my_unique_id a'),
    // keep track of which map is visible
    currentMap = map1;

unique_link.addEvent('click', function(e){
    // Prevent the default behavior, but still allow bubbling of events
    e.preventDefault();

    // Hide the current map
    currentMap.setStyle('display', 'none');

    // store the correct map by comparing the two maps and making it visible
    currentMap = (currentMap == map1 ? map2 : map1).setStyle('display', 'block');

});
```

To clarify, `currentMap = (currentMap == map1 ? map2 : map1)` is called a ternary operation. It's shorthand for if/else, which could be rewritten as:

```
if (currentMap == map1) {
    currentMap = map2;
} else {
    currentMap = map1;
}

currentMap.setStyle('display', 'block');
```

Next, why do you need to remove the events on the links in each map? Couldn't they stay attached when you toggle between maps?

Lastly, you asked about event delegation and accessing values on click. Here is an example how how it works in MooTools:

```
// We pass an array of map1 and map2 through $$ to make sure that the returned value is an element collection
// So we can use addEvent on both elements.

// The event "type" we would have passed to addEvent has changed, using a psuedo event called "relay", which handles event delegation
// It takes a selector for matching elements

// The function that is passed to addEvent has two arugments, e, which is the event object, and element, which is the element that the
// event is being delegated to.
$$([map1, map2]).addEvent('click:relay(a)', function(e, element){
    // Prevent the default behavior of the anchors
    e.preventDefault();

    // element argument is the anchor. So you can access it this way.
   element.get('href');

   // or "this" can also be used.
   this.get('href');

});
```